# How to dynamically access multi level object Java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I have an API that returns a parent with its children, I need to implement that in java 8 to be able to return them as below:

A -> has B as Child, and C as Child -> C has C.1 as a sub child, and so on, The idea is we don't know the depth of the object (how many sub-sub child it got) So we need to perform a dynamic loop to access each child and sub child and set their values. I was able to set only the parent and only his one level child, but couldn't think of an idea that does what I want.
Any helo would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
private TrainingCategoryDTO methodOne(Long companyId, Long trainingCategoryId){

    TrainingCategory trainingCategory = createTrainingCategory(companyId, trainingCategoryId);
    List<TrainingCategoryChildDTO> trainingCategoryChildDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(trainingCategory.getChildrenIds())) {
        trainingCategory.getChildrenIds().forEach(childId -> {
            TrainingCategory childTrainingCategory = createTrainingCategory(companyId, childId);


            TrainingCategoryChildDTO trainingCategoryChildDTO =  converterService.convert(childTrainingCategory, TrainingCategory.class, TrainingCategoryChildDTO.class);
            trainingCategoryChildDTOList.add(trainingCategoryChildDTO);
        });
    }

    TrainingCategoryDTO trainingCategoryDTO = converterService.convert(trainingCategory, TrainingCategory.class, TrainingCategoryDTO.class);
    trainingCategoryDTO.setChildren(trainingCategoryChildDTOList);

    return trainingCategoryDTO;
}
```

Comment: Today is an excellent day to learn about the [Builder design pattern](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/exploring-joshua-blochs-builder-design-pattern-in-java).

Comment: Just suggest use lombok.  
https://projectlombok.org/   You only need define enough 
`@Getter, @Setter`
Finally, you can set level by level.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, You mean I can achieve that with Builder DP?

Comment: Lombok offers [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation. But firstly, I suggest you implementing it by hand.